# ResultSetMetaData returning BigDecimal insted of int

Tags: java, jdbc

Need some help regarding jdbc metadata.
I am using ResultsetMetaData to get metadata of columns of a table on **Oracle10g**. I am using ojdbc14.jar. There is a field in table ID declared as Number . This field is being read with jdbc at runtime to get its metadata attributes. **ResultSetMetaData.getColumnClassName()** is returning **java.math.BigDecimal** while I am expecting it to be Integer or int or long or Long type.
I even tried creating table with statement with explicitly defining **int** type for ID column as

```
CREATE TABLE COST_DETAILS ( ID **INT** Primary Key...
```

but still ResultSetMetaData is returning BigDecimal for ID column.

Is there any way to create table with any particular column type so that it will retrun int/long type?

or is ResultsetMetaData always returns BigDecimal for Oracle.

Answer (score 6):

I think Oracle numbers will always map to BigDecimal as Oracle does not store them as a binary int so this is an exact mapping. [Oracle datatypes](http://download-east.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00213) and [Oracle JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/java.101/b10979/datacc.htm) You can make floating point numbers come as a binary

Answer (score -1):

No. That's up to the driver.

You can have something like:

```
if( class == "BigDecimal" ) {
    return "Integer" 
} else if ( ....
```

And return integer instead of bigdecimal. That's what most people do.

Comment: In an auxiliary method used to determine which java type belongs to which sql type There is actually a class in apache utils library to do something like this, I can't find it though.  Something like this: getJavaType( rsmd.getType( column ) ) ; // or something like that